# Why does my cron job sometimes fail on wget: unable to resolve host address

Tags: cron, wget

My cron job runinng properly .But sometimes it get fail with following error message"
failed: No address associated with hostname.
wget: unable to resolve host address "

Comment: What part of the error message is unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will happen when one of the below are true,

1. name server in your machine cannot do dns name resolution.
2. default gateway on your machine to outside network is down or configured to not allow  outgoing traffic.

Comment: what on earth causes this answer to be -1, enlighten me for what i may have missed.

Comment: These are just some unfounded random shots in the dark because we don't know any details about the problem at hand or the network infrastructure or anything, also there might be many more reasons for this problem to happen.

Comment: what you call random shot is actually understanding of SSH and networking concept and part of it is i have faced this issue in past, but off-course if solution happens to be anything other than what i suggested i will come back and agree with you.